# How to do inclusive range queries when only half-open range is supported (ala SortedMap.subMap)

Tags: java, generics, api-design

#### On `SortedMap.subMap`

This is the API for [`SortedMap<K,V>.subMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap%28K,%20K%29):

> `SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)` : Returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys range from `fromKey`, inclusive, to `toKey`, exclusive.

This inclusive lower bound, exclusive upper bound combo ("half-open range") is something that is prevalent in Java, and while it does have its benefits, it also has its quirks, as we shall soon see.

The following snippet illustrates a simple usage of `subMap`:

```
static <K,V> SortedMap<K,V> someSortOfSortedMap() {
    return Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<K,V>());
}
//...

SortedMap<Integer,String> map = someSortOfSortedMap();
map.put(1, "One");
map.put(3, "Three");
map.put(5, "Five");
map.put(7, "Seven");
map.put(9, "Nine");

System.out.println(map.subMap(0, 4));
// prints "{1=One, 3=Three}"

System.out.println(map.subMap(3, 7));
// prints "{3=Three, 5=Five}"
```

The last line is important: `7=Seven` is excluded, due to the exclusive upper bound nature of `subMap`. Now suppose that we actually need an **inclusive** upper bound, then we could try to write a utility method like this:

```
static <V> SortedMap<Integer,V>
subMapInclusive(SortedMap<Integer,V> map, int from, int to) {
    return (to == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      ? map.tailMap(from)
      : map.subMap(from, to + 1);
}
```

Then, continuing on with the above snippet, we get:

```
System.out.println(subMapInclusive(map, 3, 7));
// prints "{3=Three, 5=Five, 7=Seven}"

map.put(Integer.MAX_VALUE, "Infinity");
System.out.println(subMapInclusive(map, 5, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
// {5=Five, 7=Seven, 9=Nine, 2147483647=Infinity}
```

A couple of key observations need to be made:

- The good news is that we don't care about the type of the values, but...
- `subMapInclusive` assumes `Integer` keys for `to + 1` to work.

  - A generic version that also takes e.g. `Long` keys is not possible (see related questions)
  - Not to mention that for `Long`, we need to compare against `Long.MAX_VALUE` instead
  - Overloads for the numeric primitive boxed types `Byte`, `Character`, etc, as keys, must all be written individually
  - A special check need to be made for `toInclusive == Integer.MAX_VALUE`, because `+1` would overflow, and `subMap` would throw `IllegalArgumentException: fromKey > toKey`
- This, generally speaking, is an overly ugly and overly specific solution

  - What about `String` keys? Or some unknown type that may not even be `Comparable<?>`?

So the question is: is it possible to write a general `subMapInclusive` method that takes a `SortedMap<K,V>`, and `K fromKey, K toKey`, and perform an inclusive-range `subMap` queries?

#### Related questions

- [Are upper bounds of indexed ranges always assumed to be exclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440282/are-upper-bounds-of-indexed-ranges-always-assumed-to-be-exclusive)
- [Is it possible to write a generic +1 method for numeric box types in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834522/is-it-possible-to-write-a-generic-1-method-for-numeric-box-types-in-java)

---

#### On `NavigableMap`

It should be mentioned that there's a [`NavigableMap.subMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) overload that takes two additional `boolean` variables to signify whether the bounds are inclusive or exclusive. Had this been made available in `SortedMap`, then none of the above would've even been asked.

So working with a `NavigableMap<K,V>` for inclusive range queries would've been ideal, but while `Collections` provides utility methods for `SortedMap` (among other things), we aren't afforded the same luxury with `NavigableMap`.

#### Related questions

- [Writing a synchronized thread-safety wrapper for `NavigableMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839267/writing-a-synchronized-thread-safety-wrapper-for-navigablemap)

---

#### On API providing only exclusive upper bound range queries

- Does this highlight a problem with exclusive upper bound range queries?
- How were inclusive range queries done in the past when exclusive upper bound is the only available functionality?

Comment: `NavigableMap` is the replacement for `SortedMap`, introduced because the latter does not support some of these operations.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my implementation for a general inclusive submap. Here I am assuming that since the maps are sorted the time complexity of tailmap will be low, so the trick is to start with the tail and look at the keys returned, and then based on those keys either take a tail, the regular submap, or the submap with the next key:

```
static <K, V> SortedMap<K,V>
subMapInclusive(SortedMap<K,V> map, K from, K to) {
    if(to == null) return map.tailMap(from);

    //What appears at key "to" or later?
    Iterator<K> keys = map.tailMap(to).keySet().iterator();

    //Nothing, just take tail map.
    if(!keys.hasNext()) return map.tailMap(from);

    K key = keys.next();

    //The first item found isn't to so regular submap will work
    if(!to.equals(key)) return map.subMap(from, to);

    //to is in the map

    //it is not the last key
    if(keys.hasNext()) return map.subMap(from, keys.next());

    //it is the last key
    return map.tailMap(from);
}
```

Comment: Nice thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do something like:

```
static <K, V> SortedMap<K,V>
subMapInclusive(SortedMap<K,V> map, K from, K to) {
  SortedMap<K,V> result = map.subMap(from, to);
  V last = map.get(to);
  if (last != null) result.put(to, last);
  return result;
}
```

EDIT: also TreeMap seems to have a subMap(K fromKey, boolean fromInclusive, K toKey, boolean toInclusive) method; perhaps you can use that instead of a SortedMap.

Comment: This wouldn't work because the definition of submap is that it is a view of the map, specifically in the API: "The returned map will throw an IllegalArgumentException on an attempt to insert a key outside its range." which would necessarily be true in the case of adding to.

Comment: I didn't think about that. If you don't want to keep that property of the result I think you could do
   SortedMap<K,V> result = new TreeMap<K,V>();
   result.putAll(map.subMap(from, to));
but it's not exactly the prettiest thing.
Otherwise you could try using NavigableMap which directly extends SortedMap and has the method with booleans (which is were TreeMap inherits it from). It really seem like it's a bad call from the designers that SortedMap doesn't also have the method with the booleans.

Comment: `subMap(fromKey, toKey)` is 
equivalent to `subMap(fromKey, true, toKey, false)`. Docu: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap(K,%20K).
So the `fromKey` is included. The `toKey` is NOT included (false).

So we need to use `subMap(fromKey, true, toKey, true)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Guava's Maps.filterKeys?

```
Maps.filterKeys(map, Range.closed(0, 4)); //includes 1 and 3
Maps.filterKeys(map, Range.closed(3, 7)); //includes 3, 5, and 7
```

Arguments to the Range predicate must implement Comparable, but you can also use Predicates.in to filter using a collection:

```
Set<Integer> filterSet = Sets.newHashSet();
filterSet.add(3);
filterSet.add(5);
filterSet.add(7);
Maps.filterKeys(map, Predicates.in(filterSet)); //includes 3, 5, and 7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get a submap of **SortedMap** or **TreeMap**:

`subMap(fromKey, toKey)` is
equivalent to `subMap(fromKey, true, toKey, false)`. Docu: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap(K,%20K).

In above call the `fromKey` is included. The `toKey` is NOT included (false).

So we need to use `subMap(fromKey, true, toKey, true)` to include both ranges.