# Split Java ArrayList by properties of contained Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` containing Objects that have a date value. 
Now I want to manage to create a new `ArrayList` for each year that contains all the Objects from the main `ArrayList` that have the same year in their date Value.

So all Objects from 2010 go in one List, all from 1999 in another.

Comment: create list iterator and while iterating create new list for each distinct date entry, I don't know why would that make you do any good but its a try ..

Comment: Did I get that wrong? Those `Object` s are `Date` s? Before answering (or even hearing) your question, I'd suggest using generics (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.htm) to parameterize your `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Andeas_D: If you don't get a question, imagine a "How do I do that?" as third sentence.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a [`Map<Year,List<DatedObject>>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), maybe even [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) like a [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

You can also use [multimap from Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Essentially you map from each year (perhaps just an `Integer`), the `List<DatedObject>` that belong in that year.

And since years have a natural sorting order, you may want to see if `SortedMap` provides you with functionalities that you need. Most likely the answer is yes.

---

#### The Map Example

Here's a snippet in Java that shows you how you can populate the map. Note also that [`NavigableMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) is used instead of `SortedMap`; `NavigableMap` allows inclusive range queries (see related question).

```
    class DatedObject {
        final String name; final int year;
        DatedObject(String name, int year) {
            this.name = name; this.year = year;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s (%d)", name, year);
        }
    }
    List<DatedObject> masterList = Arrays.asList(
        new DatedObject("A", 2010),
        new DatedObject("B", 2009),
        new DatedObject("C", 2006),
        new DatedObject("D", 2010),
        new DatedObject("E", 2009),     
        new DatedObject("F", 2011)          
    );
    NavigableMap<Integer,List<DatedObject>> objectsByYear =
        new TreeMap<Integer,List<DatedObject>>();
    for (DatedObject obj : masterList) {
        List<DatedObject> yearList = objectsByYear.get(obj.year);
        if (yearList == null) {
            objectsByYear.put(obj.year, yearList = new ArrayList<DatedObject>());
        }
        yearList.add(obj);          
    }
    System.out.println(objectsByYear);
    // prints "{2006=[C (2006)], 2009=[B (2009), E (2009)],
    //          2010=[A (2010), D (2010)], 2011=[F (2011)]}"
    System.out.println(objectsByYear.get(2011));
    // prints "[F (2011)]"
    System.out.println(objectsByYear.subMap(2007, true, 2010, true));
    // prints "{2009=[B (2009), E (2009)], 2010=[A (2010), D (2010)]}"
```

#### Related questions

- [How to do inclusive range queries when only half-open range is supported (ala SortedMap.subMap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857680/how-to-do-inclusive-range-queries-when-only-half-open-range-is-supported-ala-sor)

---

#### The Partitioned List

If you absolutely insists on a `List<List<DatedObject>> partitionedList`, then build the map as above, and simply follow it with:

```
List<List<DatedObject>> partitionedList =
    new ArrayList<List<DatedObject>>(objectsByYear.values());
System.out.println(partitionedList);
// prints "[[C (2006)], [B (2009), E (2009)], [A (2010), D (2010)], [F (2011)]]"
```

---

#### The MultiMap Example

You can also use `Multimap` from Guava, and [`Multimaps.index`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) utility method as follows:

```
    Multimap<Integer,DatedObject> mmap = Multimaps.index(
        masterList,
        new Function<DatedObject, Integer>(){
            @Override public Integer apply(DatedObject from) {
                return from.year;
            }
        }
    );
    System.out.println(mmap);
    // prints "{2010=[A (2010), D (2010)], 2009=[B (2009), E (2009)],
    //          2006=[C (2006)], 2011=[F (2011)]}"
```

#### API Links

- [`com.google.common.collect.Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)
- [`com.google.common.collect.Multimaps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html)
- [`com.google.common.base.Function`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r8/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<Integer, List<YourObject>> yearLists = new HashMap<Integer, List<YOurObject>>();
List<YourObject> originalList = ...; //initialized or received from somewhere

for (YourObject object : originalList) {
    int year = object.getDate().getYear(); //or something
    List<YourObject> yearList = yearLists.get(year);

    if (yearList == null) {
        yearList = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
    }

    yearList.add(object);
    yearLists.put(year, yearList);
}
```

I hope I didn't make much mistakes there..

Answer (score 4):

The [Multimaps.index()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) method in Guava will do this for you.

Comment: +1; will finally download Guava so I can write a snippet example and add to my answer if you don't mind.