# Maplike data structure

Tags: java

Is there a map like data structure with integer as key , string as value, which ends up to be sorted by key no matter on insertion order like when you insert first item {4, somevalue} that it will be on the fourth place when you use it in further application flow

Comment: Fourth place? Could you explain that? 4th place if you insert 3 more items with keys lower then 4 ? Or always 4th place? Even if you don't insert anything? What would then be on the first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`interface SortedMap<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) defines a type that has the behavior you're looking for:

> A [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that further provides a total ordering on its keys. The map is ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) typically provided at sorted map creation time. This order is reflected when iterating over the sorted map's collection views (returned by the `entrySet`, `keySet` and `values` methods).

A particular implementation of a `SortedMap` that may be of interest is a [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> A [Red-Black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) based [`NavigableMap`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed `log(n)` time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations.

Note that `interface NavigableMap<K,V> extends SortedMap<K,V>`. That is, a `NavigableMap` is a `SortedMap`, but it also specifies additional methods, e.g. all-inclusive bounds `subMap`. If you don't need these additional functionarlities, simply a `SortedMap` should work just fine.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Collections](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

---

#### Example

This shows basic usage of `NavigableSet<K,V>`:

```
    NavigableMap<Integer,String> nmap =
        new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
    
    nmap.put(3, "Three");
    nmap.put(1, "One");
    nmap.put(4, "Four");
    nmap.put(5, "Five");
    nmap.put(7, "Seven");
    
    System.out.println(nmap);
    // {1=One, 3=Three, 4=Four, 5=Five, 7=Seven}

    System.out.println(nmap.firstKey()); // 1
    System.out.println(nmap.lastEntry().getValue()); // Seven
    System.out.println(nmap.higherKey(1)); // 3 
    System.out.println(nmap.lowerEntry(6).getValue()); // Five

    NavigableMap<Integer,String> sub = nmap.subMap(2, true, 5, true);
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : sub.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%s => %s%n",
            entry.getKey(),
            entry.getValue()
        );
    }
    // 3 => Three
    // 4 => Four
    // 5 => Five
```

#### Related questions

On basic `Map` manipulation:

- [Iterate Over Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-map)
- [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

Others of interest:

- [Why doesn’t Java Map extends Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extends-collection)

On `SortedMap` vs `NavigableMap`:

- [How to do inclusive range queries when only half-open range is supported (ala SortedMap.subMap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857680/how-to-do-inclusive-range-queries-when-only-half-open-range-is-supported-ala-sor)
- [Writing a synchronized thread-safety wrapper for NavigableMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839267/writing-a-synchronized-thread-safety-wrapper-for-navigablemap)

Comment: what about when I'm reading back from that map, which mechanism would I use for writing values based on indexes and if index is not next number write -(dash) or nothing. `ex: for nmap printed back would be one,-,three,four,five,-,seven`  Should I ask another question for this?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for [`java.util.TreeMap<Integer, String>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).  It orders the entries based on the key.

Comment: I wouldn't says by "hash key", as that could be interpreted that the order depends on the `hashCode()` return value. It orders base on the key.

Comment: It's based on the key's natural ordering, or alternatively, a supplied Comparator.